# elasticsearch on Ec2 cannot hit public IP(timeout)

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch running on EC2,

I can hit form local IP address(ex. curl -XGET localhost:9200)

I cannot hit from public IP address, whether on the same machine, or from our network, it always times out,

IPtables are allowing

port is open(to itself as well as private network)

Elasticsearch http.cors is enabled and allows "*"

aside from Iptables, amazon security config, elasticsearch config could there be anything I am overlooking? (we can access 443 and get kibana up, it just times out on the elasticsearch ajax call or if I try to access 9200 directly)

been working on this for over a day so I humbly come to you all!

thank you

Comment: Double check your amz security config and ensure that the ports are allowed from the source (or 0.0.0.0) for tcp. Reboot the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue.

I managed to solve it as follows:

1. Do what [TJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174184/tj) said in his comment, + restart the instance. I wasn't sure if this was/is necessary, but I did it for good measure.
2. I made sure that the following is set in the elasticsearch.yml file:
   a.  http.enabled: true
   b.  http.cors.enabled: true
   c.  http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
3. Restarted elasticsearch (service elasticsearch restart)

Then when I tried to access elasticsearch from the public IP it worked - http://[PUBLIC IP OF INSTANCE]:9200

Hope this helps.

Comment: turns out inside of this it was a rogue firewall mixed with the amazon security config that was causing issues! I hate working on boxes that arent documented haha

Answer (score 0):

I just spent lots of time trying to get this working and just succeeded.

Setup: Elasticsearch 6.2.4, running on a Windows Server 2012, EC2 instance.

I also installed the discovery-ec2 plugin, not sure now if it is required, my assumption is, yes it is required although some of the settings it allows were not necessary to get it working.

**Config (.yml)**. I tried tons of different .yml config settings which in the end did not help, in the end I think the main setting is:
 network.host: 0.0.0.0

I tried setting the network.host to *ec2:privateIpv4* and *ec2:publicIpv4* (plugin settings) but they didn't help.

I had added the required Custom TCP Rules (allowing 9200 and 9300...not sure if 9300 is needed).

Either it failed to start (usually with a binding to 9300 error) or started but was not publicly accessible.

**The Fix**. What got it working in the end is you **must** also [open the port in windows firewall](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-open-a-port-in-windows-firewall-on-windows-server-2012). As soon as I added the inbound rule, boom it connected :)

I then stripped out all the extra configs I had been trying, restarted Elasticsearch... and it still worked!