# Unable to connect to Elasticsearch through aws public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have elasticsearch running on EC2 (Fedora),

I am unable to connect externally using the public ip or hostname.

ElasticSearch starts correctly and I can access locally on the machine using: curl -XGET http://localhost:9200

```
{
  "name" : "Prodigy",
  "cluster_name" : "awstutorialseries",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "72cd1f1a3eee09505e036106146dc1949dc5dc87",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-11-18T22:40:03Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

And I do follow all the steps explained here: [elasticsearch on Ec2 cannot hit public IP(timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508721/elasticsearch-on-ec2-cannot-hit-public-iptimeout/28158799#28158799)

like

1. Do what TJ said in his comment, + restart the instance. I wasn't sure if this was/is necessary, but I did it for good measure.
2. I made sure that the following is set in the elasticsearch.yml file: a. http.enabled: true b. http.cors.enabled: true c. http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
3. Restarted elasticsearch (service elasticsearch restart)

I can connect kibana[image]
But I can't connect to elasticsearch[image]

my inbound and outbound are wide open for this instance:[image] [image]

this is my elasticsearch.yml file [image]

Comment: Can you show your `elasticsearch.yml` file content?

Comment: You correctly poked a hole in the firewall, but there is nobody listening on that port. This can happen if the server is configured to listen on `127.0.0.1`. Change it to `0.0.0.0` and it will work.

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency Thank you it relay solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

For EC2 you need to install the AWS Plugin that is provided by elasticsearch. Once plugin is installed, you need to generate secret-key and access-key from EC2. [This](http://pavelpolyakov.com/2014/08/13/elasticsearch-cluster-on-aws-part-1-preparing-environment/) link should help you generate the required keys.
After this you need to configure following settings in your elasticsearch.yml : network.host: *ec2*,network.publish_host: "", discovery.type: ec2,cloud.aws.access_key: , cloud.aws.secret_key: ,discovery.ec2.groups: ,discovery.ec2.host_type: "public_ip", discovery.ec2.ping_timeout: "10s"

This should get you up and running. Connect from your client using the ip address of your machine.

Comment: also add 
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false,
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [<all client IPs> ]